# SQL search fail when querystring is text

Tags: sql, asp.net, vba

Trying to access an **Access** database with ASP and the following lines work fine when the querystring is a number "ProductID" in the following example.

```
If Len(Request.QueryString("ProductID")) <> 0 Then
  strSQL="SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ProductID="
  rst.Open(strSQL & Request.QueryString("ProductID")), _ 
  conn, 0, 1
```

But if the querystring is text say ProductName then the following error pops up

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e10'
> [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected
> 2.

I am using the Northdb.mdb from "Access 2019 programming by example with VBA, XML, and ASP" by Julitta Korol

Comment: try this `strSQL & "'" & Request.QueryString("ProductID") & "'"`

Comment: This one works. Many thanks. However, it comes another problem, if the querystring return a one single word like "Ikura" then it works perfectly. However is the querystring return more than one word like "Grandma's Boysenberry Spread" it will flag an error.
**[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'ProductName='Grandma's''.** 
If the querystring returns encounter more than one word, only the first word will be returned.
**http://localhost/NorthDB/ProductLookup.asp?ProductName=Alice** where the productname should be **Alice Mutton**

Comment: Converted my comment to an answer :) You may have to refresh the page to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Please mention datatype of `ProductID` column. If it's string then you can use single quote around your parameter.

```
If Len(Request.QueryString("ProductID")) <> 0 Then
  strSQL="SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ProductID='"
  rst.Open(strSQL & Request.QueryString("ProductID")&"'"), _ 
  conn, 0, 1
```

Comment: The datatype of ProductID is Autonumber while other like ProductName is short text

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in comments, you have to pad your parameter with single quote. For example

```
strSQL & "'" & Request.QueryString("ProductID") & "'"
```

> This one works. Many thanks.  However, it comes another problem, if the querystring return a one single word like "Ikura" then it works perfectly. However is the querystring return more than one word like "Grandma's Boysenberry Spread" it will flag an error.

In such cases you will have to escape the single quote. You can do that by replacing `'` by `''` as shown below.

```
strSQL & "'" & Replace(Request.QueryString("ProductID"), "'", "''") & "'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved when I work with the .accdb file instead of the .mdb file. Something must be wrong with the original database.